# Firebase-admin won't initialize on a next js app deployed on Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js, firebase-hosting, firebase-admin

I'm trying to deploy a Next JS app to Firebase hosting using the web framework option firebase-tools has. The only issue I've encoutered is that firebase-admin seems to never initialize when I try to use it to fetch data, or do anything related with it.
This is how I'm initializing it, it works locally:

firebase/firebaseAdminInit.ts

```
import admin from 'firebase-admin';

export function GetFirebaseAdminApp() {
    if(admin.apps.length === 0){
        const app = admin.initializeApp({
            credential:admin.credential.cert({
                clientEmail: process.env.NEXT_FIREBASE_CLIENT_EMAIL as string,
                projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID as string,
                privateKey: process.env.NEXT_FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY as string
            }),
            databaseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL as string,
            storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STORAGE_BUCKET as string
        });
        return app;
    }
    return admin.app();
}
```

How I use it:

lib/repository/products.ts

```
import { getFirelord, getFirestore, getDocs, query, orderBy, limit, offset, getCountFromServer, addDoc, updateDoc, getDoc, deleteDoc } from "firelord";
import { ProductsMetaType } from "./dtoModels";
import { Product, ProductRequest, productToDomain, productType_toDto } from "../domain/Products";
import { GetFirebaseAdminApp } from "../../firebase/firebaseAdminInit";
import { PagedQuery, PagedResult } from "../domain/PagedQueries";
import formidable from "formidable";
import { DeleteImage, UploadImage } from "./objectStorage";

const app = getFirestore(GetFirebaseAdminApp()); //This should return the firebase-admin app
const productFl = getFirelord<ProductsMetaType>(app, 'Products');

export async function GetAllProducts() {
    const docs =
        await getDocs(productFl.collection()).then(qSnapshot =>
            qSnapshot.docs.map(docSnapshot => docSnapshot.data())
        ).then(dtoArr => dtoArr.map(productToDomain))
    return docs;
}
```

When I try to log the app in the firebaseAdminInit.ts file I see that there's something, not a undefined or null value, but when it gets used somewhere else it fails saying it's not initialized:

> FirebaseAppError: The default Firebase app does not exist. Make sure
> you call initializeApp() before using any of the Firebase services.

Comment: Seems like if I directly call the admin.initializeApp method inside the products.ts file it works. I would not like to define everything that needs the app in just one big file.
I'll try dependency injection and export the functions that handle the logic from the file where I initialize firebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like if I try to get the app by checking if there's an app already initialized, or if I define a function checking in what env I'm working on (dev or prod) I'll always get an error. `firebase-admin` **NEEDS** to be initialized like this to run on firebase functions:

```
const app = admin.initializeApp({
    credential:admin.credential.cert({
        clientEmail: process.env.NEXT_FIREBASE_CLIENT_EMAIL as string,
        projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID as string,
        privateKey: process.env.NEXT_FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY as string
    }),
    databaseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL as string,
    storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STORAGE_BUCKET as string
})
```

This will give me errors when testing locally (dev) but it will work on prod, which is annoying having to rewrite this block of code each time I want to deploy or test locally.

I used dependency injection to pass the app to all the functions that need `firebase-admin` and I'm exporting them from the file where `firebase-admin` is being initialized, but I haven't tried just getting the app by writing `admin.app()`, that might work too.

I'm also having a lot of errors now with firebase functions parsing the body of a request each time and issues with authorization and the name of cookies, so I would recommend others to wait for the web framework support for next js to be better if you want to deploy on firebase as me.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue when I was trying to use firebase-admin in Next.js API Routes (run in server). Your workaround helped we figuring out what was the issue. Calling directly admin.app() or getApp() will cause error in firebase functions. Instead use getApps()[0]. I do not know the reason.

With the code below, I imported succesfully `adminAuth` and `adminFirestore` from API Routes (run in server).

lib/firebase-admin.ts

```
import { AppOptions, cert, getApps, initializeApp, ServiceAccount } from "firebase-admin/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase-admin/auth";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase-admin/firestore";

const credentials: ServiceAccount = {
  projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_ADMIN_SDK_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  privateKey: process.env.FIREBASE_ADMIN_SDK_PRIVATE_KEY?.replace(/\\n/g, "\n"),
  clientEmail: process.env.FIREBASE_ADMIN_SDK_CLIENT_EMAIL,
};

const options: AppOptions = {
  credential: cert(credentials),
};

export const initializeFirebaseAdmin = () => {
  const firebaseAdminApps = getApps();
  if (firebaseAdminApps.length > 0) {
    return firebaseAdminApps[0];
  }

  return initializeApp(options);
}

const firebaseAdmin = initializeFirebaseAdmin();

export const adminAuth = getAuth(firebaseAdmin);
export const adminFirestore = getFirestore(firebaseAdmin);
```

Comment: This way I can initialize it differently based on which env the code is running. I found a lot of cryptic errors like these when deploying and working with firebase experimental web framework option. I haven't touched this project in months but I hope the documentation on limitations get's better instead of trying 1000 things before finding what's causing an error.